# question with modal verbs and do/does

Tags: modal-verbs, questions

You should buy three apples.
question form -

> How many apples you should buy?

Is this correct? Or should it be:

> How many apples should you buy?

---

Also, think about this one, if you buy three apples, which one is the correct question form:

> How many apples do you buy?

or:

> How many apples you buy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question is easy; use:

> How many apples should you buy?

In place of *should*, you could also use *would, could, did, will*, or even *might*, depending on what you were trying to say.

---

In the second question, you can say:

> How many apples do you buy?

However, by itself, I'd interpret that to mean:

> How many apples do you buy *on a regular basis*?

I might fit that into a conversation like this one:

> I go to the orchard every Saturday, and buy apples.
>   *Really? How many apples do you buy?*

However, if someone told me something different, I would ask my question in a different way:

> I will go to the orchard on Saturday, and buy apples.
>   *Really? How many apples **will** you buy?*

Comment: Great answer, +1. From the context of the question ("If you bought three apples, what...") I think that in the second sentence, the OP is looking for "How many apples *did* you buy" ("I bought 3 apples.").

Comment: @WendiKidd: Great point; I'll add that to the list of words one could use.